# R using cell values from a data frame as arguments in an already defined custom function

Tags: r, apply

I am relatively new to R and programming in general, so my question might be due to a lack of experience and cryptic error messages. I have done a fair amount of investigation and experimenting with different versions of apply and functions in the plyr package. The root of my question is how to have the value from a cell in a data frame be supplied as an argument in my function? I'll do my best to provide example data.

I am working with survey data in R, so I have a data frame with many columns and rows. I created a custom function to process some of the data. I run the script for the function first, so that it is loaded in the workspace in RStudio. The function has two arguments:

```
myfunction <- function(id, info){
  # various data processing
}
```

myfunction does not return anything. When using real data, it outputs some .CSVs for me, so I don't need to get anything back from it - just need it to run using the values from every row.

For the sake of this example, lets say my data frame (called mydata) only has two columns (and in fact, I can subset it down to just these two columns in the overall process if needed for the solution).

```
ID Gender
 1    M
 2    F
 3    F
 4    M
```

What I would like to happen, is have R go through each row and provide the values of the cells as the two arguments in myfunction:

```
# So for the first row, it should do
myfunction("1", "M")
# And the second:
myfunction("2", "F")
```

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
a_ply(mydata, c(1,2), print)
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
  Gender
1   M
2   F
3   F
4   M
```

Which seems like it is in the right direction, but whenever I put myfunction in the a_ply I can't get it to work the way I want. I either get this error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'X' not found
## Which I believe is actually an error from myfunction, which would mean the
## ID value is not passing through to it correctly
```

Or when playing around with different versions of that a_ply command, I get this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument
```

Thanks in advance for any help, so far I've been able to make it this far reading documentation and lots of other posts here, but I can't seem to find anything explaining this.

Comment: you can try `apply(mydata,1, function(x) myfunction(x[1],x[2]))`

Comment: I think I have seen this before, and maybe I am just misunderstanding what it means. The actual myfunction is 86 lines of code. Does the whole function need to be defined within the apply()?

Comment: After trying this, it does seem to work. However, I have a print("Your data has been processed successfully") at the end of myfunction. After running that apply, I get this output:

`[1] "Your data has been proccessed successfully."
[1] "Your data has been proccessed successfully."
[1] "Your data has been proccessed successfully."
[1] "Your data has been proccessed successfully."
[1] "Your data has been proccessed successfully." "Your data has been proccessed successfully." "Your data has been proccessed successfully."
[4] "Your data has been proccessed successfully."`

is it running 8 times?

Comment: `apply` is looping over each row in mydata (hence the 1) and is putting out an output from your function for each iteration. See: `?apply`

Comment: Right, but mydata only has four rows. So it should only run four times -- where are the other four iterations coming from?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what is being printed in `myfunction`. Do you get the correct number of .csv files?

Answer (score 0):

(For completion and closing the question):

```
apply(mydata,1, function(x) myfunction(x[1],x[2]))
```